# Trouble getting a Python script to execute

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to experiment around with brute forcing Bitcoin Brain Wallets via a Python script I pulled from github. How ever I am unable to get the script to run properly. I cannot get the requirements to install properly and running the script without returns:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CCTrollz\Desktop\bruteforce-bitcoin-brainwallet-master\bbb.py", line 7, in <module>
    from lib.blockchain import Abe, BlockchainInfo, Insight
  File "C:\Users\CCTrollz\Desktop\bruteforce-bitcoin-brainwallet-master\lib\blockchain.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests`

[Github Project](https://github.com/dan-v/bruteforce-bitcoin-brainwallet)

Comment: Pardon my noobiness

Comment: Did you `pip install requests`?

Comment: I will try, I am new to python and thought `pip install requirements.txt` would do that

Comment: Worked. cheers M8